# Вылетает приложение при поиске AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

В активити расположен `AutoCompleteTextView`, вот собственно код:

Вот то, что находится в `onCreate`:

```
clientATV = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.clientATV);
List<Client> clientsList = getClientList(orderForm);
NamesAdapter namesAdapter = new NamesAdapter(OrderActivity.this, R.layout.activity_order, R.id.lbl_name, clientsList);
clientATV.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
```

Код адаптера взял на просторах интеренета, мне нужно было, чтобы поиск происходил не только с начальных символом, а и с середины строки:

```
public class NamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Client> {

    Context context;
    int resource, textViewResourceId;
    List<Client> items, tempItems, suggestions;

    public NamesAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Client> items) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.items = items;
        tempItems = new ArrayList<Client>(items); // this makes the difference.
        suggestions = new ArrayList<Client>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_item, parent, false);
        }
        Client names = items.get(position);
        if (names != null) {
            TextView lblName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_name);
            if (lblName != null)
                lblName.setText(names.name);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
     */
    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((Client) resultValue).name;
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>2) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (Client names : tempItems) {
                    if (names.name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(names);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<Client> filterList = (ArrayList<Client>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Client names : filterList) {
                    add(names);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

А вот класс `Client`, он содержит три поля, **id** из таблицы в БД, **наименование** и **код**.

```
 public class Client {
    public String name;
    public String code;
    public String id;

    public Client(String name,String code,String id){
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

А проблема вот в чем,я так понимаю, потому что у меня вместо массива строк, массив объектов класса `Client`, в момент поиска возможных вариантов приложение падает с вот чем:

```
    09-05 15:23:41.382 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit I/Choreographer: Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:23:42.722 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit I/Choreographer: Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:23:44.210 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit I/Choreographer: Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:23:45.745 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit D/SELECTED_ITEM_ID: 35
09-05 15:23:50.034 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-05 15:23:50.034 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3a930)
09-05 15:23:50.042 8355-8355/com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
        at com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit.OrderActivity$NamesAdapter$1.publishResults(OrderActivity.java:222)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Я так понимаю проблема в производительности, как можно оптимизировать этот момент? Может вместо класса использовать что-то другое? Мне просто нужна какая-то сущность, чтобы хранить там 3 поля.

Comment: Главный поток Вы нагружаете конечно, но критическая ошибка говорит, что во время работы цикла в `publishResults` список `filterList` был изменён. Попробуйте вместо цикла `addAll(filterList);` и после `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: @woesss, последовал Вашему совету, все работает как нужно)) летает. Спасибо, напишите как отдельный ответ, я отмечу его в качестве правильного.

Answer (score 0):

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что вам стоит распараллелить ваши задачи. Для этого воспользуйтесь потоками.

Для чтения:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads?hl=ru

https://habr.com/post/124484/

Comment: Т.е. правильно будет в адаптере поиск вхождений подстроки (метод performFiltering)  вынести в отдельный поток или в адаптере нельзя это сделать? Не очень ещё разбираюсь в том как здесь все устроено)

Comment: @alexeyromashev попробуйте )